# Why the Create button in the main form does not work?

Tags: python, odoo

> When I click on the "Attach PDF" button, the list form opens, but the
>   "Create" button does not work. But when I go to the list form from the
>   main menu, then everything is fine. What is the problem?

**model.py**

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class AttachPDF(models.Model):
    _name = 'attach.pdf'

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string='Product', required=True)
    product_attribute_value_id = fields.Many2one('product.attribute.value', string='Attribute Value',
                                                 required=True, ondelete='cascade', index=True)
    file = fields.Binary(string="Upload file")
    file_name = fields.Char("File Name")
```

**views.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <data>  
    <record id="attach_pdf_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">Attach PDF Form</field>
      <field name="model">attach.pdf</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
          <group>
            <field name="product_id"/>
            <field name="product_attribute_value_id"/>
          </group>
          <group>
            <field name="file" widget="binary" filename="file_name" string="Binary"/>
          </group>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>

    <record id="attach_pdf_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">Attach PDF List</field>
      <field name="model">attach.pdf</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
          <field name="product_id"/>
          <field name="product_attribute_value_id"/>
          <field name="file_name" readonly="1"/>
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>

    <record id="attach_file_wizard" model="ir.actions.act_window">
      <field name="name">Attach PDF</field>
      <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
      <field name="res_model">attach.pdf</field>
      <field name="view_type">form</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
      <field name="domain" > [('product_id', '=', context.get('product_name'))]</field>
      <field name="view_id" ref="attach_pdf_view_tree"/>

    </record>

    <record id="view_form_product_attr_pdf" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">attach_pdf_attribute_product_product_template_only_form_view</field>
      <field name="model">product.template</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//header/button[@name='121']" position="after">
          <button name="%(attach_pdf_attribute.attach_file_wizard)d" context="{'product_name': name}" string="Attach PDF" type="action" class="oe_highlight"/>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>

  </data>
</odoo>
```

**I am superuser rights
Odoo 12*

thanks for your answers***

Comment: P.S. I can’t change the record either (in list form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The create button should work. all records which have `product_id` different from the current product id should be filtered.

The records are filtered using the action `domain`, if you do not see records in the tree view, it means that they are hidden.

If you need to fill `product_id` with the current product pass default values in the button context:

```
context="{'default_product_id': active_id}"
```

To filter records in the tree view and show only records related to the current product, you can use values from context as you did but it is not necessary since you can use `active_id` in the action domain:

```
<field name="domain"> [('product_id', '=', active_id)]</field>
```

***Edit:***

When you click on the create button Odoo will try to switch to the form view only if the controller that triggered the request is the current controller.

> > The current controller is the last controller in the controller stack, i.e. the currently displayed controller in the main window (not in a dialog), and null if there is no controller in the stack.

- Try to set the target to `current`, which will let you create, edit, and delete easily.

  ```
  <field name="target">current</field>
  ```
- Or you can add One2many relation (`inverse_name==product_id`) to add documents to the product template.

  **Example:**

  Add the One2many relation:

  ```
  class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
      _inherit = "product.template"

      document_ids = fields.One2many('attach.pdf', 'product_id', 'Documents')
  ```

  Add the following code after `XPath` expression.

  ```
  <notebook>
      <page string="Documents">
          <field name="document_ids" widget="one2many_list">
              <tree editable="bottom">
                  <field name="product_attribute_value_id"/>
                  <field name="file_name" invisible="1"/>
                  <field name="file" widget="binary" filename="file_name"/>
              </tree>
          </field>
      </page>
  </notebook>
  ```

Comment: Kenly, [link](https://gyazo.com/9f40801755ad19ecdcd620fb3900d586), When I click "Create", the form does not open ;(

Comment: This happens when you set the target field to `new`, check my edit.

Comment: Kenly Thank you very much! It works! Which book to read to understand Odoo well for me ?

Comment: I am glad to help, Sorry I do not know a book, but I highly recommend you to check the [developer documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/index.html) each time you add some logic and do not hesitate to check the source code documentation.